# I cannot remove row with jQuery

Tags: jquery

When I click 'add new row' to my invoice table, it dynamically adds the row.

However when I have to delete the row dynamically with the 'remove row' button it does not delete.

Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Below is my code:

```
<tbody class="body">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="count[]" value="1"><span>1</span</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="item[]" placeholder="item"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="description[]" placeholder="description"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity[]" placeholder="quantity"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control price" name="price[]" placeholder="price"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control item_discount" name="item_discount[]" value="0" placeholder="item discount"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control total" name="total[]" placeholder="total" readonly=""/></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add-row"><i class="fa fa-plus"> Add new row</i></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="remove-row"><i class="fa fa-minus"> Remove row</i></button>
</div>
```

```js
$('#remove-row').click(function() {
    $(this).parents().first().remove();
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: `$(this).parents().first()` ?  Isn't that targeting the `div` which holds the button?  How does that target a table row?

Comment: Step 1, add `<table></table>` tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your new row gets added to the end of your table do the following

```
$( 'tbody tr:last-child' ).remove();
```

If you are removing the first row of your table you will need to do the following

```
$( 'tbody tr:first-child' ).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

This selection:

```
$(this).parents().first()
```

Is targeting this element:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
```

That's *probably* not what you want to remove, especially since it holds the buttons being clicked.

Did you mean something like this?:

```
$('tbody tr').last().remove();
```

---

Keep in mind that you're also *always* removing the last (or first, if you want that one) row from the table.  If you want to remove a *specific* row from the table, you could put the button on the row itself.  Something like this:

```
<tr>
    <!-- your other table cells -->
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-row" /></td>
</tr>
```

And use event delegation to handle the click event for all rows dynamically added to the table:

```
$('tbody').on('click', '.remove-row', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: This works as expected. thanks a lot will accept the answer in 7 mins

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).parents()` selects `div.col-md-6` which is not what you want.

If you want to remove the last row in your table you should do:

```
$('#remove-row').click(function(){
    var table = $('tbody.body'); // This get the tbody element of your table

    var rowToRemove = table.find('tr').last(); // Get the last row of your table
    rowToRemove.remove();
});
```

---

But if you want to select a specific row to remove you should make a way to select rows and THEN remove them. Personnaly I would mark them as selected and then remove them like this:

```
$('tbody.body').on('click', 'tr', function(){ // Notice ON instead of CLICK, it is to select row that will be added  later on
    var row = $(this); // select the row that has been clicked
    row.toggleClass('selected-row'); // mark the row as selected
});

$('#remove-row').click(function(){
    var table = $('tbody.body'); // Select the table
    var rows = table.find('tr.selected-row'); // Select all the row that are marked for deletion
    rows.remove(); // then remove them all
});
```

Comment: for the second solution, i should add a check box with a class 'select-row' so i can select the row i want?

Comment: yes you could. You wont even have to add a class to them. Just have to search the `table` like this :`$('tbody.body').find('checkbox:checked').parent('tr').remove()` and this will do the trick. It look for every checked checkbox in the table and remove their row