# it will bring up the deleted row when thead is clicked | Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

> I want to delete datatable row permanently

if I delete all the rows, i want datatable will display the default *"No data available"* text.

**I already try some POST :** *But no luck*

**[DataTables remove row button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33424302/datatables-remove-row-button)** *with answer :*

```
$("#dataTables-example").on('click', '.btn-info', function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
```

**[I cannot remove row with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38956779/i-cannot-remove-row-with-jquery)** *with answer :*

```
$( 'tbody tr:last-child' ).remove();
```

> But, when I delete all the rows, the text "No data available" does not
>   appear.  and when `thead` is clicked, it will bring up the deleted
>   row.

========================

[**MY JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4fukuma/oawftt7z/)

**jQuery delete row :**

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteRow', function() {
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

**in dataTable func :**

```
 "columns": [
        { "data": "id"},
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "subtype"},
        { "data": "approximate_count" },
        { "data": "time_created" },
        {data: null ,
        "sClass" : "center",
        "sDefaultContent" : '<button class="deleteRow">Delete</button> '
        },
        ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For displaying default text, you can try

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "language": {
        "emptyTable": "My Custom Message On Empty Table"
    },
    rowId: id
});
```

For deleting row use,

You need to remove data from backend as well using ajax.
Than you can use below function.

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteRow', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
    var rowid = document.getElementById(id);
    var Pos = table.fnGetPosition(rowid);
    table.fnDeleteRow(Pos);
});
```

Please check jsfiddle.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/oawftt7z/2/)

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I mean.
I want if I have deleted all the rows, the dataTable will bring up the "No data available" text.
But in my jsfiddle displaying a blank table when all rows already deleted.

Comment: can you help me how to input your deleting row code into jsfiddle??

Comment: @CalvinAnanda,  why bother when @mrchidam have posted a correct answer? The above assumes you have an `id` attribute on the `<tr>`'s which you have not.

Comment: [davidkonrad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1407478/davidkonrad), @Patrik's answer was help me.

Answer (score 1):

By deleting the  element from the DOM, you are not actually deleting the data from the DataTable's memory. You have to use the [DataTable's API methods](https://datatables.net/reference/api/) to manipulate the table (add, edit, delete, etc).

Assign the return value of the DataTable() method to a variable. This is the reference to the DataTable object.

For example:

```
var table = $("myTable").DataTable({
    // DataTable options goes here
});
```

Now, to delete a particular row, use the row().remove() method in the onclick event handler of the remove button as shown below.

```
$(".removeButton").click(function () {
        table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).remove().draw();
});
```

[Here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().remove()) is the API reference for this method.

Comment: IMO the correct answer, here is OP's fiddle updated with the needed oneliner -> **https://jsfiddle.net/oawftt7z/3/**

Answer (score 0):

You should set plugin using `DataTable()`, not `dataTable()`.

Then to get the relevant row to delete, you could use: `myTable.row(':eq(' + $(this).closest('tr').index() + ')')`. Maybe there is better way but i don't know enough Datatable plugin.

See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/osy4L8pr/).

And to get custom message, as explains in [@PratikGadoya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47484855/1414562),
see [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yhwvjtje/).